# Should I use the default users model in django 1.11 for my project

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Actually, I'm working on a project where I need to save some details like name, username, password, age, gender etc of every user.

In that website, any user can login to their account, edit information.

So should I use the default users model or create a new model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default user model in Django save some limited fields about one user. fields are

```
first_name, last_name, email, password, groups, user_permissions, is_staff, is_active, is_superuser, last_login, date_joined
```

If you want to save other information of user like birthday, expertise, gender you have to write userprofile model which must be linked one to one with user.

Example:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User
 class UserProfile(models.Model): 
       user = models.OnetoOneField(User)
       birthday = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
       skills = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you subclass `AbstractUser`. This option is suitable if you're fine with Django's `User` fields, but need extra fields. Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project) also recommends to do this anyway.

> If you’re starting a new project, it’s highly recommended to set up a
>   custom user model, even if the default User model is sufficient for
>   you. This model behaves identically to the default user model, but
>   you’ll be able to customize it in the future if the need arises:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    pass or additional fields here ...
```

You also have to point to this model **before creating or running any migration** in the settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, If you want to create a custom user model for user, It's mentioned in the Django's Official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). For achieving that you have to first inherit your custom user model with AbstractUser class and then pointing that custom user in your settings file by mentioning

---

**AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'mycustom_user_app.MyCustomUser'**.

---

Now django internally knows which model is the User model for the project, and you can access all model managers(e.g. create_user, etc. ) for your custom user. In that way you can use the current models fields and also can add more fields into it. That's the legit way to go with and to customize your User Model as mentioned in the documentation